# How to Send Request to all facebook friends in facebook 3.0 android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have to send app request to all friends here i am using this code for send request to only one friend it's working fine but i want to send request to multiple/all friends

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("to", "1782990807");
    params.putString("message",
            "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            Logout.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values
                                .getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    Logout.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

here i am passing facebook id of one friend how could i send to all/multiple friends
i have facebook id of all friends
i need urgently
Thanks Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove this line params.putString("to", "1782990807");
and choose friends.You can choose multiple friends.